# error showing when using opendir()

Tags: php, wordpress

I was creating a wordpress plugin, now i got an error like

```
Warning: opendir(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/): failed to open dir: not implemented in http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/FlxZipArchive.php on line 37
Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/FlxZipArchive.php on line 38
```

and these are the files

index.php

```
<?php

$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$folder_name = $upload_dir['baseurl'];

//Don't forget to remove the trailing slash
$the_folder =$foldername;
$zip_file_name =  WP_CONTENT_DIR."/".'uploads.zip';
$za = new FlxZipArchive;
$res = $za->open($zip_file_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if($res === TRUE) {
    $za->addDir($the_folder, basename($the_folder));
    $za->close();
}
else
    echo 'Could not create a zip archive';
?>
```

FlxZipArchive.php

```
<?
/**
* FlxZipArchive, Extends ZipArchiv.
* Add Dirs with Files and Subdirs.
*
* <code>
*  $archive = new FlxZipArchive;
*  // .....
*  $archive->addDir( 'test/blub', 'blub' );
* </code>
*/
class FlxZipArchive extends ZipArchive {
    /**
     * Add a Dir with Files and Subdirs to the archive
     *
     * @param string $location Real Location
     * @param string $name Name in Archive
     * @author Nicolas Heimann
     * @access private
     **/
    public function addDir($location, $name) {
        $this->addEmptyDir($name);
        $this->addDirDo($location, $name);
     } // EO addDir;
    /**
     * Add Files & Dirs to archive.
     *
     * @param string $location Real Location
     * @param string $name Name in Archive
     * @author Nicolas Heimann
     * @access private
     **/
    private function addDirDo($location, $name) {
        $name .= '/';
        $location .= '/';
        // Read all Files in Dir
        $dir = opendir ($location);
        while ($file = readdir($dir))
        {
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
            // Rekursiv, If dir: FlxZipArchive::addDir(), else ::File();
            $do = (filetype( $location . $file) == 'dir') ? 'addDir' : 'addFile';
            $this->$do($location . $file, $name . $file);
        }
    } // EO addDirDo();
}
?>
```

Every time when executing index.php it just creating a zip file with an empty folder in it and exiting

please someone help me to fix this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`opendir()` is designed to open local directories (`file://` protocol) and since PHP 5.0.0 FTP (`ftp://`)

It seems that you're trying to pass an URL (`http://` protocol), which is not valid param for `opendir`

Comment: So what should i use insted of opendir() ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. I guess that you want to access local dir, right? If so, than the right question is what is the correct param. You should pass a regular path to the directory instead of url to `opendir` function. That's all.